# Wildfly as service: How to log just once?

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I'm running wildfly as a service on Linux.

I used the well-written instruction on http://developer-should-know.tumblr.com/post/112230363742/how-to-install-wildfly-as-a-service-on-linux that is based on a script [wildflyhome/bin/init.d/wildfly-init-redhat.sh] contained in the wildfly distribution. This script uses the declaration

`JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG="/var/log/wildfly/console.log"`

**Problem:** This configuration logs twice: Firstly in `server.log` (in wildflyhome/standalone/log) and secondly in `console.log`. This wastes storage (and maybe some performance).

Therefore I set

`JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG="wildflyhome/standalone/log/server.log"`

But now each log entry is written twice into server.log -:)

**Question:** How can I configure wildfly such that it logs just once ?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the `console-handler` from the servers configuration. By default WildFly logs to the stdout and the `server.log`. The `JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG="/var/log/wildfly/console.log"` is seeing the output from stdout.

To remove the console handler you can execute the following CLI command

```
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:remove-handler(name=CONSOLE)
```

If you want you could also remove the `console-handler` itself.

```
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:remove
```

Comment: But doesn't the service script need the console handler ?

Comment: It appears so which is a pretty bad idea really.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem with Windows Service on Wildfly 11.0.0.Final. Wildfly service created two additional log files. Example:
wildfly-stderr.2017-11-22.log
wildfly-stdout.2017-11-22.log
It saved all logs both to stdout file and to server.log.

I couldn't turn of console-handlers due to Spring Boot logging issues on old version. Instead, i edited service.bat and changed this lines:

```
if "%STDOUT%"=="" set STDOUT=auto
if "%STDERR%"=="" set STDERR=auto
```

To this:

```
if "%STDOUT%"=="" set STDOUT=""
if "%STDERR%"=="" set STDERR=""
```

It looks that after this logging work correctly(remember to uninstall and install service once again). Now it saves logs only to server.log. I tested this for a while and don't see any missing logs.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question whether the service scripts need the consol.log, I would say "yes" the default init.d scripts do need the console handler, because it greps the output to figure out when the service is up and running:

```
            cat /dev/null > "$JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG"

            if [ "$JBOSS_MODE" = "standalone" ]; then
                    start-stop-daemon --start --user "$JBOSS_USER" \
                    --chuid "$JBOSS_USER" --chdir "$JBOSS_HOME" --pidfile "$JBOSS_PIDFILE" \
                    --exec "$JBOSS_SCRIPT" -- -c $JBOSS_CONFIG $JBOSS_OPTS >> "$JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG" 2>&1 &
            else
                    start-stop-daemon --start --user "$JBOSS_USER" \
                    --chuid "$JBOSS_USER" --chdir "$JBOSS_HOME" --pidfile "$JBOSS_PIDFILE" \
                    --exec "$JBOSS_SCRIPT" -- --domain-config=$JBOSS_DOMAIN_CONFIG \
                    --host-config=$JBOSS_HOST_CONFIG $JBOSS_OPTS >> "$JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG" 2>&1 &
            fi

            count=0
            launched=0
            until [ $count -gt $STARTUP_WAIT ]
            do
                    grep 'JBAS015874:' "$JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG" > /dev/null
                    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
                            launched=1
                            break
                    fi
                    sleep 1
                    count=$((count + 1));
            done
```

Looking at it, I would say storage is not a major issue, since the script copies /dev/null into the log every time Wildfly starts. And since it greps for a given code 'JBAS015874' to know the server is up, unless you want to delete your entire server.log on every boot, you are going to have to rewrite that bit too (or it will find this string from previous startups!).

So, unless you want to rewrite all the init scripts, I'd just live with it.

Applications should not log to standard out anyways. The only thing I see there after wildfly is up and running are uncaught runtime exceptions...

Comment: "storage is not a major issue, since the script copies /dev/null into the log every time Wildfly starts" it's true only if you restart it often. When you have an istance always running (for a continuous service) where you can configure the maximum size or delete date?

Answer (score 0):

In the root-logger under domain:logging:3.0 subsystem, Comment out the

```
<handler name="CONSOLE"/> as below 

<!--handler name="CONSOLE"/-->
```

Afterward, restart your Wildfly Service. The stdout log won't be written to any longer. Hope this helps